# How to change the span display style, while changing the innerHTML of that span

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<span id="spnRef" style="display:none"></span>
```

I want to make this span visible now. How can I change the span display style, while changing the `innerHTML` of that span?

Comment: You cannot make both happen in single line of code. You have to execute that separately. Say `$("#spnRef").show();` - if you are using jquery. `document.getElementById("spnRef").style.display = "block";` - if plain JS.

Comment: JavaScript and HTML. not jquery

Comment: Added plain javascript option too...

Comment: Good. I have added as an answer, you may accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot make both happen in single line of code.

You will have to execute that line separately.

If plain javascript:

```
document.getElementById("spnRef").style.display = "block";
```

If Jquery:

```
$("#spnRef").show();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("spnRef").style.display = "block";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("spnRef").style.display = "block";
```